# How do you add text to an entry in tkinter GUI and then have it disappear when user interacts with widget?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

So I'm using tkinter python and I have an entry widget with Name text in it. I want to delete the text only when the widget is clicked on. This is what I have so far:

```
#Import tkinter to make gui
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk#Sets title and creates gui
root = Tk()
root.title("Identity Form")

#Configures column and row settings and sets padding
mainframe = ttk.Frame(root, padding="3 3 12 12")
mainframe.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N, W, E, S))
mainframe.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
mainframe.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

name=StringVar()
age=StringVar()
gender=StringVar()
#Widgets to put in items, quanitity, and shipping days
name_entry = ttk.Entry(mainframe, width=20, textvariable=name)
name_entry.grid(column=2, row=2, sticky=(W, E))

age_entry2 = ttk.Entry(mainframe, width=20, textvariable=age)
age_entry2.grid(column=2, row=3, sticky=(W, E))

male = ttk.Radiobutton(mainframe, text='Male', variable=gender, value='male')
female = ttk.Radiobutton(mainframe, text='Female', variable=gender, value='female')
other = ttk.Radiobutton(mainframe, text='Other', variable=gender, value='other')

name_entry.insert(0,'Name')
```

This creates the entry widget and has the text "Name" inside it. When it is clicked upon how I want the text to disappear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def reset(*args):
    name_entry.delete(0, END)

name_entry.bind("<Button-1>", reset)
```

Looks like the solution was simple, and I found a variation of it, but I didn't know it was necessary to use *args or it wouldn't work.

Comment: bound functions are always called with an `event` parameter

Comment: Your users might be sad if they enter information in, and then click in the entry widget to select some text. All of the data they entered will vanish.

Comment: I only want that to happen the first time. How would I change it from happening again?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve so by binding a method to set the value of the `name` variable as an empty string.

```
def reset(event):
    name.set("")

name_entry.bind("<Button-1>", reset)
```

If you only want to remove the text in the `name_entry` once, you can add an if condition to set the name only when the value of the `name` is equal to the original one.

```
def reset(event):
    if name.get() == initial_text:
        name.set("")
```

I hope my answer is helpful.